# Facing problems in uploading larger files using WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I am facing problem while uploading a file with larger size. I am using WCF service's basicHttpBinding for Request/Response where it is formed like this,

int MAXSIZE = Int32.MaxValue;

```
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        AllowCookies = false,
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
        MaxBufferSize = MAXSIZE,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = MAXSIZE,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = MAXSIZE,
        MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
        TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
        TransferMode = System.ServiceModel.TransferMode.Buffered,
        UseDefaultWebProxy = true,

    };

    binding.ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
    {
        MaxDepth = 32,
        MaxStringContentLength = MAXSIZE,
        MaxArrayLength = MAXSIZE,
        MaxBytesPerRead = MAXSIZE,
        MaxNameTableCharCount =16384,
    };
```

As per the answers over net it should work, however it is throwing an exception.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.

Does anyone encountered such situation before ?

Comment: Have you made sure that the settings are applied on both client and server side?

Comment: Yes the settings are on both. Still it is giving the same exception.

Comment: Can you enable tracing and inspect the log to know the exact reason on why you get a bad request

Comment: I enabled tracing, but not getting anything out of it. I mean I can't understand the error from obtained log statements. :(

Comment: You would need to use TraceViewer to inspect the log. Else post the log contents for us to help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to this. The problem was with the service name in web.config file of WCF service.
I was using namespace path as is. To resolve this, open svc file markup. Copy service name and use it as is in web.config file.